# LWJGL/OpenGL Vertex Buffer Object

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm currently in the process of creating a 2D, top down game using the LWJGL/OpenGL, but I'm having some issues after drawing entities, in getting them to move around, after they've been rendered using Vertex Buffer Objects. This is the run() method of the rendering thread, along with setUp methods:

```
// Render thread
public void run() {
    setUpDisplay();
    setUpOpenGL();
    setUpEntities();
    while (isRunning) {
        getFPS();
        drawEntities();
        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
        if (Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }
    destroyEntities();
    Display.destroy();
    System.exit(0);
}   

// Initialisation method for the display
private void setUpDisplay() {
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        Display.setTitle("Roguelike");
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Initialisation method for OpenGL
private void setUpOpenGL() {
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    lastFrame = Main.getTime();
}
```

And entities inherit these methods from an abstract superclass to set up the VBOs and to draw the entities (the drawEntities method in the render thread simply calls that method, and the entity update method (see below), while setUpEntities calls the setUp method):

```
// Method to initialise VBOs for a given entity
public void setUp() {
    vertexData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(12);
    vertexData.put(getVertices());
    vertexData.flip();

    textureData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(12);
    textureData.put(textureVertices);
    textureData.flip();

    vboVertexHandle = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    vboTextureCoordHandle = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboTextureCoordHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

// Method to draw the entity
public void draw() {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, loadTexture(this.textureKey).getTextureID());

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vboVertexHandle);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vboTextureCoordHandle);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

So far I've been attempting to move a single entity across the screen to get translations to work, but to no avail - I've tried using the following update method for the entity to update its position, however it results in a trail of copies of the entity being drawn across the screen, which is obviously not what I intended:

```
public void update(int delta) { // Updates the position of the object
    this.x += this.dx * delta;
    this.y += this.dy * delta;
    this.setBounds();
    this.vertexData.rewind();
    this.vertexData.put(getVertices());
    this.vertexData.flip();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vboVertexHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Here is the result of using this method (the sprite is just a placeholder I drew in a minute to demonstrate the issue) - [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFDQV.jpg)

Any help would be very much appreciated, if you need any more information I'll update this.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Quick note, getVertices():

```
public float[] getVertices() {  // Returns array of vertices (for vertex VBO)
    float[] vertices = {    this.bounds[0], this.bounds[3], this.bounds[2], this.bounds[3],
                            this.bounds[2], this.bounds[1], this.bounds[2], this.bounds[1],
                            this.bounds[0], this.bounds[1], this.bounds[0], this.bounds[3] };
    return vertices;
}
```

And setBounds() is as follows:

```
public void setBounds() {
    this.bounds[0] = this.x;
    this.bounds[1] = this.y;
    this.bounds[2] = this.x + this.width;
    this.bounds[3] = this.y + this.height;
}
```

Which effectively updates to new x/y values when the method is called.

Comment: You need to clear the buffer between frame renders

Comment: *facepalm* I knew it'd be something daft like that, thanks haha, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you don't clear the buffers.

You need to clear the buffers or the new rendered data will just be added onto the old data.

To clear the buffer you need to do the following.

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

If you are using `GL_DEPTH_TEST`, then remember to clear that as well. (This is more just so you know)

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks haha, I literally just forgot to add that line in the render loop... Won't be making that mistake again in a hurry.

Comment: Happens to most of us! ;)